# Issue with .Hide() on individual widgets in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

As someone pretty new to wxpython, I'm attempting to write a login script for an imaginary program. On startup, buttons ask if you want to create a new account or register a new one. When either one is clicked, I want all the widgets on the page to disappear, leaving a blank frame for other widgets to be imposed on. However I'm not sure how to .Hide() specific widgets -- my existing widgets are not being recognized as variables. Here's my relevant code:

```
class Welcome(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "ImageViewer", size=(500,350))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Welcome to ImageViewer. Do you have an account?", (50,10))
        font = wx.Font(12, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)  
        text.SetFont(font)  

         yesbutton = wx.Button(panel, label="Yes,  I wish to log in", pos=(50,150), size=(150,60))
         self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.loginwindow, yesbutton)

        nobutton = wx.Button(panel, label="No,  I wish to register", pos=(270,150), size=(150,60))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.registerwindow, nobutton)


    def loginwindow(self, event):
        self.Hide(self.text) #Error occurs here
```

> AttributeError: 'Welcome' object has no attribute 'text'

I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this (if there is please let me know) but for now I'm just not sure why I can't access these variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` isn't made an attribute of of the `Welcome` class, so when you try and call it in your `loginwindow` function it's out of scope.

When you declare it in your `init` method make it self.text

Edit: This code works.

```
class Welcome(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, "ImageViewer", size=(500,350))
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    self.text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Welcome to ImageViewer. Do you have an account?", (50,10))
    font = wx.Font(12, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)  
    self.text.SetFont(font)  

    yesbutton = wx.Button(panel, label="Yes,  I wish to log in", pos=(50,150), size=(150,60))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.loginwindow, yesbutton)


def loginwindow(self, event):
    self.text.Hide() #Error occurs here
```